# OleProcedure() C++ Builder 10.3

Tags: com, c++builder, ole

I try to select 10 characters in Word document with C++ Builder.

VBA method looks as follows:

```
Selection.SetRange Start:=0, End:=10
```

How to correctly pass parameters to C++ Builder method?

I tried several options, but did not succeed.

```
selection.OleProcedure("SetRange", Start:=0, End:=10)
selection.OleProcedure("SetRange", "Start:=0", "End:=10")
selection.OleProcedure("SetRange", 0, 10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OleProcedure()` does not support **named parameters** <sup>1</sup>.  You have to pass the parameter values in the same order that [they are declared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.setrange) by the COM object, which in this case is:

```
expression.SetRange(Start, End)
```

So `selection.OleProcedure("SetRange", 0, 10)` should work just fine.  If it is not, you need to be more specific about what exactly is not working for you.

<sup>1: if you want to use named parameters, you will have to access the variant's held `IDispatch` interface and call its [`IDispatch::Invoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oaidl/nf-oaidl-idispatch-invoke) method directly, providing it with a [`DISPPARAMS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-dispparams) struct containing the desired names and values.</sup>